# iOS7 Smart Banner Disappearing

Tags: ios7, smartbanner

We are having an issue where smart banners appear in Safari on iOS6, but when testing in Safari on iOS7 with non 5s devices the banner briefly appears (sort of a placeholder without content) and then disappears.  We have tested other sites other than ours and it seams to be consistent behavior.  dropbox.com cnn.com usatoday.com all have smart banners visible with Safari iOS6, but that are disappearing when reached from Safari iOS7 from iPhone4, iPhone4s, iOS Simulator, iPhone5.

Is anyone else seeing this behavior?

Comment: Does @schellsan answer helped you? Was that it?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same behaviour on iOS8.

It turns out that the ID I grabbed from the app store url was prefixed with "id". Once I removed that prefix it started working as expected.

In this example URL
`http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/ditchtv/id1042361181?mt=8`, the meta tag should be:

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1042361181">`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Same happened here. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this same problem, but only for apps that have not been built with the iOS7 SDK. My older apps that have been compiled with the iOS <= 6 SDK will show an app banner on phones running iOS <= 6, but only apps compiled with iOS SDK == 7 will show on a phone running iOS 7.